# Why do we use "dafür" in this sentence?

Tags: preposition

How do we know that we have to use "dafür" in this sentence? Why "dafür" and not some other "da-word"?

> Ich will auch, dass du glücklich bist, aber nicht genug, um etwas dafür zu tun.

Comment: What other _da-word_ would you find plausible or what would you expect instead?

Comment: "damit" maybe? Considering that the verb "tun" is often used in the following way: "zu tun haben mit".

Comment: Another question: What do you think this sentence means?

Comment: The following is the translation of that sentence; I want you to be happy too, but not enough to do anything about it.

Comment: do about sth (what shall we do about the open points?); do with sb (we will do that jointly with the other group); do with sth (we could do with some paint so that we can finish this room); do sth (we do our tasks); How do I know? with? about? No particle? I have to pick the right form according to what I want to express. It's the same in German. You have to learn and know the meaning with the particles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing verb constructions with the same verb here.

It's true that there is

*mit jemandem/etwas zu tun haben* (to deal with someone/something)

In your above sentence, there is no *haben* though, which is crucial in this construction. Thus we can rule this out.

Another construction with *tun* is

*etwas für jemanden/etwas tun* (to do something for someone/something)

So a way to identify the correct *da-word* would be to start backwards. What do you want to say in English, find out what the appropriate (infinitive) form in German is and then find the corresponding *da-word*.

Addendum:

There is also

*etwas gegen jemanden/etwas tun* (to do something against someone/something)

which would then require *dagegen*.